# Load array of textures into individual Image components into a grid layout in Unity 4.6 (using uGUI)

Tags: c#, arrays, image, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to develop a loader that grabs a group of textures located in an array and populates them into a grid layout. Could anyone share some code insight or a snippet that might do the trick?

Comment: Are you using Unity Canvas UI Grid Layout Group ? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html

Comment: I am using a Grid Layout Group. Just a little extra info as well - The images are for a drag and drop puzzle game where users can assemble animals. There are a bank of 6 buttons (Horns, Head, Eyes, Body, Legs, Tail) When they click a button it loads a different group of images into the Grid Layout Group (and removes the previous group). Any help with this would be a lifesaver.

Comment: I suggest watch this video (layouts) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAdW_K44Dao then watch this video (drag and drop) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c47QYgsJrWc

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to show your images in the format below. What you can do is merging your images into a 1 big Texture2D (But as I know image size should not exceed 2048x2048)

[image: illustration]

The function below should do the work:

```
private Texture2D ConcatTexture(Texture2D[,] textures, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{
    int rowCount = textures.GetLength(0);
    int columnCount = textures.GetLength(1);

    //Space allocation for the final texture
    Texture2D finalTexture = new Texture2D(columnCount * imageWidth, rowCount * imageHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        for(int j=0 ; j < columnCount ; j++)
            finalTexture.SetPixels(j * imageWidth, (rowCount-i-1) * imageHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, textures[i, j].GetPixels());

    return finalTexture;
}
```

You can also edit this code and put some spaces between images if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think that will work for me as each image needs to be an individual object so it can be dragged out of the grid layout and dropped onto the play area.